# Callback function of with() returns empty collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have three tables: `realties`, `room_types` and `realty_room_type`:

```
realty_room_type
----------------
id
realty_id
room_type_id

room_type
----------------
id
code
```

In my `Realty` model I set a `rooms()` relationship:

```php
public function rooms()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Room::class);
}
```

I am trying to eager load the `rooms()` relationship using the `with()` method. I want to custom what is returned from the relationship, so I am passing a callback function like this:

```php
$realty = Realty::
    where('id', $realtyId)
    ->with([
        'rooms' => function ($query) use ($realtyId) {
            $query
                ->leftJoin('room_types', 'room_types.id', '=', 'realty_room_type.room_type_id')
                ->selectRaw('code, COUNT(*)')
                ->groupBy('code');
        }
    ])
    ->get()
);
```

The problem is I get an empty collection when accessing the relationship using `$realty->rooms`. Any idea why?

However if I dump and die the statements of the callback function like this:

```php
Realty::
    where('id', $realtyId)
    ->with([
        'rooms' => function ($query) use ($realtyId) {
            dd($query
                ->leftJoin('room_types', 'room_types.id', '=', 'realty_room_type.room_type_id')
                ->selectRaw('code, COUNT(*)')
                ->groupBy('code'));
        }
    ])
    ->get()
);
```

I get what I'd like to be in the `rooms()` relationship.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not how `with()` works. You should define relationships and maybe use `withCount` to count one of the relationships (it depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve).

Comment: try it after removing `->get();` in the callback method !

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads).

Comment: @louisfischer I've read the docs before, man. :)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin then how can you say that this is not how `with()` works? I did not know of `withCount()`, thank you. I'll have a look at it. It may do what I want to do. I will let you know.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `return` inside `callback` function and call `get()`. [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) you can find the details.

```
$realty = Realty::
where('id', $realtyId)
->with([
    'rooms' => function ($query) use ($realtyId) {
        $query
            ->leftJoin('room_types', 'room_types.id', '=', 'realty_room_type.room_type_id')
            ->selectRaw('code, COUNT(*)')
            ->groupBy('code');
    }
])
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Still getting an empty collection. I edited my question though, good catch.

Comment: try to debug corresponding parameter value and its record

Comment: What do you mean?